# SEM - how to obtain better fit indicators for a sem analysis using lavaan in R or Stata

Tags: r, stata, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am quite new to SEM analysis so I'm trying to figure out how to make my model a good one (whether drop a variable or something else?) I have tried all sorts of things in order to make my chisquared/df better or the RMSEA, or the SRMR, almost nothing changes the result. I have 6 latent variables measured by 32 items with 380 observation overall. The analysis concerns consumer's intention of purchasing a self-driving cars so I am using the TAM model (Technology acceptance model, Davis 1989) in order to prove that this model can also be applied  on this particular topic. So I have 380 answers to an on-line survey, 6 latent variables which influence each other like this: 
    IT -> PEOU 
    PEOU -> PUp
    A <- PUp PUs PEOU 
    A ->BI
4 of these variables are the classical used in the TAM (so perceived usefulness, perceived ease of use, attitude and behavioral intention). I have added two variables which are perceived usefulness at a social level and interest for new technologies.

Each of the variables is explained by several factors:
    IT -> i_13 to i_18
    PUp -> p_19 to p_26
    PUs -> s_31 to s_37
    PEOU -> u_27 to u_30
    A -> a_38, a_39 and a_41
    BI -> b_42 to b_44

I have obtained a great Cronbach's alpha for all the constructs, and also the factor loadings are quite good, I wouldn't know how to proceed from here.

Here is the output I get in lavaan using R:

```
Number of observations                           380
Estimator                                         ML
Minimum Function Test Statistic             2067.433
Degrees of freedom                               427
P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Model test baseline model:

Minimum Function Test Statistic            10662.284
Degrees of freedom                               465
P-value                                        0.000

User model versus baseline model:

Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.839
Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.825

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

Loglikelihood user model (H0)             -18308.403
Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)     -17274.686

Number of free parameters                         69
Akaike (AIC)                               36754.806
Bayesian (BIC)                             37026.677
Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)        36807.754

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

RMSEA                                          0.101
90 Percent Confidence Interval          0.096  0.105
P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

SRMR                                           0.213

Parameter Estimates:

Information                                 Expected
Standard Errors                             Standard

Latent Variables:
                Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
PUp =~                                                                
P_19              1.000                               1.457    0.850
P_20              0.940    0.047   20.164    0.000    1.369    0.818
P_21              1.053    0.044   24.048    0.000    1.535    0.903
P_22              1.040    0.046   22.692    0.000    1.516    0.875
P_23              0.909    0.049   18.560    0.000    1.324    0.777
P_24              0.744    0.054   13.888    0.000    1.085    0.635
P_25              0.697    0.053   13.029    0.000    1.016    0.605
P_26              1.049    0.048   21.971    0.000    1.530    0.860
PUs =~                                                                
S_31              1.000                               1.139    0.724
S_32              1.191    0.080   14.960    0.000    1.357    0.790
S_33              1.155    0.074   15.619    0.000    1.316    0.824
S_34              1.281    0.082   15.687    0.000    1.459    0.828
S_35              0.702    0.066   10.565    0.000    0.800    0.562
S_36              1.088    0.076   14.271    0.000    1.239    0.754
S_37              1.130    0.077   14.758    0.000    1.287    0.779
PEOU =~                                                               
U_27              1.000                               1.163    0.791
U_28              1.208    0.057   21.195    0.000    1.404    0.921
U_29              1.285    0.059   21.694    0.000    1.494    0.938
U_30              1.183    0.069   17.110    0.000    1.376    0.787
IT =~                                                                 
I_13              1.000                               1.132    0.798
I_14              1.084    0.057   18.999    0.000    1.228    0.856
I_15              1.066    0.053   20.191    0.000    1.207    0.897
I_16              0.913    0.057   16.081    0.000    1.033    0.754
I_17              1.154    0.071   16.287    0.000    1.307    0.762
I_18              0.739    0.063   11.703    0.000    0.837    0.581
A =~                                                                  
A_38              1.000                               1.381    0.818
A_39              1.021    0.059   17.256    0.000    1.411    0.786
A_41              0.855    0.063   13.626    0.000    1.181    0.656
BI =~                                                                 
B_42              1.000                               1.501    0.890
B_43              1.110    0.040   27.573    0.000    1.666    0.940
B_44              0.849    0.050   16.875    0.000    1.274    0.714

Regressions:
               Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
PEOU ~                                                                
IT                0.535    0.057    9.334    0.000    0.521    0.521
PUp ~                                                                 
PEOU              0.795    0.067   11.829    0.000    0.634    0.634
A ~                                                                   
PEOU              0.238    0.055    4.335    0.000    0.201    0.201
PUp               0.626    0.051   12.304    0.000    0.660    0.660
PUs               0.314    0.046    6.879    0.000    0.259    0.259
BI ~                                                                  
A                 0.986    0.055   17.890    0.000    0.907    0.907

Covariances:
               Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
PUs ~~                                                                
IT                0.425    0.080    5.335    0.000    0.330    0.330

Variances:
               Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
P_19              0.813    0.068   11.936    0.000    0.813    0.277
P_20              0.927    0.075   12.357    0.000    0.927    0.331
P_21              0.536    0.050   10.665    0.000    0.536    0.185
P_22              0.703    0.061   11.467    0.000    0.703    0.234
P_23              1.148    0.090   12.710    0.000    1.148    0.396
P_24              1.742    0.131   13.311    0.000    1.742    0.597
P_25              1.791    0.134   13.381    0.000    1.791    0.635
P_26              0.826    0.070   11.780    0.000    0.826    0.261
S_31              1.175    0.095   12.343    0.000    1.175    0.475
S_32              1.110    0.096   11.609    0.000    1.110    0.376
S_33              0.817    0.074   10.996    0.000    0.817    0.321
S_34              0.977    0.089   10.918    0.000    0.977    0.315
S_35              1.386    0.105   13.186    0.000    1.386    0.684
S_36              1.165    0.097   12.060    0.000    1.165    0.431
S_37              1.070    0.091   11.757    0.000    1.070    0.393
U_27              0.806    0.065   12.409    0.000    0.806    0.374
U_28              0.354    0.040    8.756    0.000    0.354    0.152
U_29              0.303    0.041    7.385    0.000    0.303    0.119
U_30              1.164    0.093   12.452    0.000    1.164    0.381
I_13              0.730    0.062   11.758    0.000    0.730    0.363
I_14              0.551    0.052   10.580    0.000    0.551    0.268
I_15              0.355    0.039    9.020    0.000    0.355    0.196
I_16              0.808    0.066   12.270    0.000    0.808    0.431
I_17              1.235    0.101   12.197    0.000    1.235    0.419
I_18              1.377    0.104   13.208    0.000    1.377    0.663
A_38              0.943    0.086   10.997    0.000    0.943    0.331
A_39              1.229    0.106   11.571    0.000    1.229    0.382
A_41              1.849    0.145   12.770    0.000    1.849    0.570
B_42              0.592    0.061    9.669    0.000    0.592    0.208
B_43              0.364    0.058    6.246    0.000    0.364    0.116
B_44              1.562    0.122   12.796    0.000    1.562    0.490
PUp               1.270    0.130    9.779    0.000    0.598    0.598
PUs               1.297    0.163    7.939    0.000    1.000    1.000
PEOU              0.985    0.110    8.914    0.000    0.728    0.728
IT                1.282    0.140    9.170    0.000    1.000    1.000
A                 0.445    0.064    6.993    0.000    0.233    0.233
BI                0.398    0.066    6.047    0.000    0.177    0.177

R-Square:
               Estimate
P_19              0.723
P_20              0.669
P_21              0.815
P_22              0.766
P_23              0.604
P_24              0.403
P_25              0.365
P_26              0.739
S_31              0.525
S_32              0.624
S_33              0.679
S_34              0.685
S_35              0.316
S_36              0.569
S_37              0.607
U_27              0.626
U_28              0.848
U_29              0.881
U_30              0.619
I_13              0.637
I_14              0.732
I_15              0.804
I_16              0.569
I_17              0.581
I_18              0.337
A_38              0.669
A_39              0.618
A_41              0.430
B_42              0.792
B_43              0.884
B_44              0.510
PUp               0.402
PEOU              0.272
A                 0.767
BI                0.823
```

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Your question is not clear. Could you provide us more information about your problem? There might be many ways to improve model fit. However, without more (and specific) information about your analysis, data/variables, and goals, it would be difficult for others to help.

Comment: Sure. I am doing a social analysis on consumer's intention or purchasing new technological products so I am using the TAM model (Technology acceptance model, Davis 1989) in order to prove that this model also can be applied nowadays on this particular topic. So I have 380 answers to an on-line survey, 6 latent variables which influence each other like this: IT -> PEOU, PEOU -> PUp, A <- PUp, PUs, PEOU and finally A ->BI

Comment: Please edit the new information into the question.

Comment: There is not (I believe) a good answer to this question. Your model is incorrect. To get a better fit, you need a better model.

Comment: In what way my model is incorrect? Too many variables?

Comment: You could have a look at using `modindices(your.model)`, there you might find indications of paths, covariances etc. that might be important but are missing from your model.